# My plot window shows up with the right axis but the plot is blank. The plot is only filled if I change the plot style to red dots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a plot for simple projectile motion. My set up is as follows:

```
#Input know values
v_x = 20 #m/s
v_yo = 20 #m/s
#a = -g = -9.81 m/s^2 (vertical direction only)
a = -9.81 #m/s^2
T = 4 #s
t = 0.1

#import plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Analytical solution
#x = v_x*t
#y = v_yo*t + 0.5*a*t**2

while t < 4:
    x = v_x*t
    y = v_yo*t + 0.5*a*t**2
    t+=0.01
    plt.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

The plot window comes up but it just won't show anything. When I replaced
plt.plot(x,y) with plt.plot(x,y,'ro') then it comes out fine. But that makes my points look huge. Is there a way to make it look like a smooth curve?

Answer (score 0):

`plt.plot(x, y, marker = 'o', color = 'black', size = '8')`

See the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html) on different types of markers.

Answer (score 0):

In `pyplot`, the `plot` functions default is to plot lines between sequences of points, put not the points themselves.  This is because the default style for plotting is `'b-'`, or a blue solid line.  But this only shows if your input has multiple points.  For instance,

```
plt.plot([0,1],[5,6])
plt.show()
```

will produce a single line between the points `(0,5)` and `(1,6)`.  When you call `plt.plot()` on only a single input for `x` and `y`, it is plotting a line between the first points and nothing.  I.e. the line is never plotted.

By changing the style argument from its default to `'ro'`, you are telling matplotlib to plot each point as a red circle instead of plotting a line between each pair of points.  And as you pointed out, the circles can be pretty big.

There are several ways to remedy your code: plot dots instead of circles, or make the circle small, or keep a list of all of your x and y coordinates and plot them as a line.

#### Option 1

Change your plot style to `'r.'` will produce small red dots:

```
plt.plot(x,y, 'r.')
```

[image]

#### Options 2

Adding a `markersize` argument can alter the size of the circles:

```
plt.plot(x,y, 'ro', markersize=0.3)
```

[image]

#### Option 3

You can also keep a list of all of your points and plot them together:

```
x_list = []
y_list = []
while t < 4:
    x = v_x*t
    y = v_yo*t + 0.5*a*t**2
    t+=0.01
    x_list.append(x)
    y_list.append(y)

plt.plot(x_list,y_list)
plt.show()
```

[image]